# What would be the best cryptocurrency Trading website

Tags: cryptocurrency

Can anyone direct me to the best cryptocurrency/bitcoin trading website.  I need to make some money very quickly. I was scammed previously and I want to be able to get back on my feet again.  I definitely learn my lesson and conversing with a trade manager through WhatsApp app clearly was a big mistake. I have to somehow recoup what I lost which is a lot of money!

Comment: If there was a way to make some money very quickly we'd all be rich.

Comment: Anyone who tells you they know a way how you can make money very quickly with no risk or labor involved is lying to you. Especially when cryptocurrency is involved. Nobody is in the business of giving people money for nothing.

Comment: `Can anyone direct me to the best cryptocurrency/bitcoin trading website. I need to make some money very quickly` and `I definitely learn my lesson` are two sentences that completely cancel each other; if you're still trying to make money quickly through crypto you haven't learned anything

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of an A/B problem.

> I need to make some money very quickly.

Get-rich-quick schemes are a surefire way to lose your money (or get into legal trouble, depending on who/what you're dealing with). You might as well go to the casino and put it all on black (I wouldn't recommend that either)

> I definitely learn my lesson

I'm not sure you have...

> I have to somehow recoup what I lost which is a lot of money!

It's a sunk cost. Cut your losses and move on. I suggest you take a look at the existing questions for ways to get back on your feet and generate income in a sustainable way.

Comment: @Lee,  these are very wise words that I hope you listen to.

Comment: If you have 10,000 and owe a notorious criminal 20,000 and you know he will kill you if you don’t pay up, and nobody is lending you money, then everything on black is a good strategy :-( Casinos are usually honest.